# What is faster a mysql primary key or lucene index

Tags: mysql, performance, lucene

I want to use a SHA 256 hash as key for all paths on a big data storage. 
Now I want to know if I should use a database like mysql to store the keys or an index tool like lucene. 
I have around 1 billion SHA 256 keys to search for them. With which tool (mysql or lucene) I could search faster for a specific SHA 256 key?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: No data that I know of.

Comment: This is an opinion-based question, and not really a good fit for stackoverflow. It's also unclear, as we know nothing else about your app and what your database needs are, outside of looking up something in an index.

Comment: A billion rows with a "random" PK (sha-1, md5, UUID, etc) -- That will run at essentially the same speed as the disk -- one disk hit per row fetched.  (Literally years to fetch all rows randomly from spinning disk!)  I doubt if Lucene can go any faster, but I do not know.  (I am assuming you don't have enough RAM to hold the entire table.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory Lucene should be faster - it has constant time hash-based lookup for such fields and scales easily.

MySQL index is tree based, so the lookup time will grow logarithmically.

I did compare performance of both on large data sets, albeit for a different purpose, and the results I have confirm this.

That said there are many ways to optimize both. Depending on the version of MySQL there are different indexing options, you could also partition the table and also use full text capabilities of MySQL. Lucene has many tricks up its sleeve as well. Ultimately the choice comes down to particulars of the hardware and number of lookups per second and other auxiliary factors.